# Удалённый запуск кода

Tags: c#, .net

В общем реализовал код, который автоматически может менять обложку в вк (у меня смена происходит по таймеру пока). 
И тут возникает вопрос, а где можно запускать код, а точнее чтобы он сам запускался, и чтобы я в этом уже не участвовал. Предполагаю как-то на сервере, но не могу придумать как. Может ли мне кто-то описать план примерный или может даже решение предложить?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону связки `quartz` + `topshelf`. В интернете очень много инфы по данной паре, да и на этом форуме тоже )

Comment: @AntonKomyshan не могу понять вот что. Если я запущу программу через консоль, она будет всегда работать? В какой момент она остановится?

Comment: Это всё Вы сами настраиваете. Можно что бы она бесконечно выполнялась, раз в сутки например, или выполнить несколько раз и закрыть. Всё в ваших руках.

Comment: @AntonKomyshan удалил свой комментарий, понял, что не верен. Тогда другой вопрос. Получается приложение лучше запускать на каком-либо сервере (если компьютер периодически выключаю)?

Comment: Смотря что Вам нужно. Если это нужно только вам - то можете и на домашнем ПК запускать. Если это связано с бизнесом - то конечно нужен сервер.

Comment: @alladuh можно воспользоваться планировщиком винды. Он может запускать задачку при включении/выключении. Подробнее почитать [тут](https://goo.gl/gjB28r) можно.